# How can I write a Visual Studio macro to perform an Extract Class refactoring?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, macros

**I'm trying to build a macro for Visual Studio 2008 that behaves thusly:** (Extract Class Macro)

I highlight some text in the currently open document and call the Macro (using a keybinding or whatever).

The macro runs "Project.AddClass" for the current active project, allowing me to specify the Class name.

The macro adds the text I originally had highlighted in the other document into the newly-created class file, and removes the text from the original file.

The text is added to the new file inside the new class body, i.e. inside the opening and closing braces.

I've been tinkering with it, but I can't get a handle to the created class document.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I like about 10% of the features of Resharper, but it really seems to bog down my environment. Plus, I'm a cheapskate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a macro to do this today and found your question while seeing whether others had done it - although its a couple of years late as an answer goes here is one :)

Updated Feb 2012 - The macro project can now be found here:
http://plisky.net/main/macros/documentation

Comment: It's never too late! We actually wound up getting resharper.